# uGUI и стандартное GUI юнити (game object->UI) это одно и то же?

Tags: unity3d

uGUI и стандартное GUI юнити (game object->UI) это одно и то же?

Comment: нет. методы `OnGUI`, плагин (платный между прочем) `nGUI` и новые компоненты `UI` это совсем не одно и тоже.

Comment: @pavel ТС говорит не про nGUI, а про uGUI. А это как раз таки юнитевская штука... а это как раз таки uGUI==UI System.... Хотя с методом OnGUI она правда ничего не имеет

Comment: Вы под `uGUI`  подразумеваете возможность  описывать интерфейс в методе `OnGUI()` или все же `canvas`? Потому, что многие именно `uGUI` называют `UI system`, которое как раз вызывается через `game object->UI`.... И оно не было стандартным когда-то... А вот **стандартное** GUI юнити было давно и оно работало в `OnGUI()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uGUI` это и есть новое (примерно с 4.5 версии) `GUI`. Работает с `canvas`.
По крайней мере так его некоторые называют. На оффициальном сайте такого названия не обнаружил.

Чтобы не было путаницы:

- через OnGUI рисуется так называемый [Immediate Mode GUI (IMGUI)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html)
- [NGUI](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/2413) (не реклама!) сторонний платный плагин

Comment: Пожалуйста, не надо вручную синонимизировать все метки unity и unity3d. Я сделал заявку на мете: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3240